# Next view controller showing at end of video in movieplayer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having a bit of a weird problem that I haven't quite been able to figure out.  I'm Guessing it has something to do with the view hierarchy but haven't been able to find a solution to it.  The problem I'm having is that once the video finishes in the movieplayer the next view that I would be seguing to is showing up in the movie player with a black backround and white text.  I know it has to do with the next view already being loaded into memory but I don't understand why it is being displayed once the video finishes playing.

I have a movieFinishedCallback method

```
- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:player];
    [player stop];
    [player.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

and have inserted a breakpoint right at the point that it is called, so the view is being displayed even before the movieplayer is removed from the current view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a link to a screen shot I took to give a better idea.  Sorry not enough rep to post an image.

http://i968.photobucket.com/albums/ae164/ecwasnthere/AppProblem.png

Comment: Are you using an MPMoviePlayerViewContoller?

Comment: No, I tried to switch over to that but the same problem occurred.

Comment: I edited my question and linked a screenshot of the problem I'm having to give a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding player.fullscreen = NO; before calling removeFromSuperview

Comment: Unfortunately no luck, it still is showing the next view controller before the movie player exits.